# PineScript Question - How to test calculations/debugging

Tags: debugging, testing

I'm currently converting an old Basic program into Pine Script. In Basic it is easy to output variable's values to test they are correct, using the PRINT statement. Would you be able to advise how I can see the values of calculations in Pine Script, please? Here is an example:

```
fn_z_to_v(c,u) =>
u = abs(c)
z3 = int(u)
q = int(z3 / 30) + 1
z7 = int(fnw((z3 / 30 - int(z3 / 30)) * 30))
```

It should be noted that these are intermediate calculations and are not intended for display in a chart. Their values would make no sense in the context of time or price.

How might I see the values of u, z3, q and z7 (assuming I correctly pass the values c and u to the function and that the function fnw is correctly formed)?

Thanks,

Comment: with the latest version of Pinescript, you have access to tables that you can place in various positions of the chart. Have you tried just putting the particular values in question in a table cell?

Answer (score 0):

PineUnit provides unit test functionality for Pine Script. After you are fine with your calculations, you can deactivate the tests and nothing is shown on your chart.

https://www.tradingview.com/script/HIQiZXdL/